# How to improve prime ng dropdown performance for huge data

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I have used primeng multi-select dropdown in our angular project. But the data which we need to load is very huge like 4-5K elements. So my dropdown takes 10 seconds during loading.

Please suggest me the way to improve the performance to create the multi-select dropdown.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PrimeNG v8 (and, in my experience, v7) has two documented properties that involve improving performance of MultiSelect inputs with very long lists of options:

`[virtualScroll]="true" itemSize="30"`

`virtualScroll` enables the basic performance enhancement but failing to set the `itemSize` value prevents improved performance.

`itemSize` affects the amount of vertical space allotted to options in the displayed options panel and `30` provides an acceptable height for rendering a checkbox and adjacent single line of text for each option in that panel.

Typically, when using MultiSelect templating with images or options larger than a single line of text, increasing the `itemSize` appropriately will be necessary. (Though less likely, you might be able to cram more entries in with a smaller font and a reduced `itemSize`.)

See "Virtual Scrolling" section of "Documentation" tab in the [primefaces.org PrimeNG documentation for MultiSelect](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect).

Comment: IMHO this should be the accepted answer, in my case having completed the CSS for the item pTemplate I assumed itemSize might no longer be necessary, removed it and it was like the p-multiSelect was readonly as clicking on it did nothing and it was 10 seconds or more before it loaded it was so slow (around 10k items). Putting itemSize back in ([virtualScroll]="true" remained present) and it loaded instantaneously. Perhaps the control API could be improved but they're free so can't complain!

Comment: Thanks for this. I had missed it in their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You should fork [primeng repo](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng) and change implementation in multiselect component ([line 51](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/multiselect/multiselect.ts#L51))

It uses *ngFor ti list values, but you should change it with [ng2-vs-for](https://github.com/kamilkp/ng2-vs-for)

The difference beweeet ngFor and vs-for is that not all elements added to the dom at once, but only the items you should see according to the scroll position.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than fork the library, which leaves you stuck on a specific version, I identified which dropdowns had so many values that they were lagging and changed these primeng dropdowns for primeng autocompletes and the lag was gone.